# After deploy: There was no endpoint listening at ipaddress/service.asmx that could accept the message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, wcf, soap

My asp.net MVC application calls a wcf web service, it works fine on my machine, but when I publish it on our own staging server I get the error:

> Inner Exception: No connection could be made because the target
>   machine actively refused it IPADDRESS:8080
>
> Message: There was no endpoint listening at
>   http://IPADDRESS:8080/SERVICE.asmx that could accept the
>   message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.
>   See InnerException, if present, for more details.

This is the web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="SERVICEWebIntegrationSoap" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://IPADDRESS:8080/SERVICEwebintegration.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SERVICEWebIntegrationSoap" contract="SERVICEServiceReference.SERVICEWebIntegrationSoap" name="SERVICEWebIntegrationSoap" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

How I said it works on local as well as the service responds well if I use the url http://IPADDRESS:8080/SERVICEwebintegration.asmx in the browser.
Any idea?

Comment: What is the config setting of your service?

Comment: @JrTabuloc the service is not mine